# How to activate only one window of an app to the foreground?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I am using a multiple-monitor setup. Every time I click on a window of an app, it will bring all windows of that app to the foreground, which hides some other apps on the other monitor. This is very annoying as I usually look at the other app at the same time.

EDIT: based on the comment, different apps may behave differently. I am wondering whether there is a window manager app to make all apps work this way.

Comment: Which specific application is this?

Comment: @patrix no specific application, i want all apps behave this way

Comment: Safari works like that already, so not all applications behave the same.

Comment: @patrix Ahem, almost all apps behave like that? Do you mean when using Cmd+Tab or clicking the Dock-Icon that all windows come to front, perhaps?

Comment: @LangLangC No, I meant the way the OP asked (click on a window raises only the clicked window, not all open windows of an application). Works that way in Safari (and probably most others), but apparently not for some applications the OP is using.

Comment: @patrix My bad formatting. Only the first sentence was really directed at you. AFAIK all native Cocoa apps should behave like we mean. I only can think of ported Java and Qt apps that do not, or some modal dialog like thing mixed in. – I still think the OP confuses app activation and single window raising.

Comment: New to mac and had the same question. The only way I see is to "hide" the other window (command-H). So when you bring focus to one of the window the hidden window won't get the focus too (because it's minimized).

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the app's icon in the Dock, you can select the individual windows that the application has open.

Only that window will be brought forward.

Comment: is there a keyboard shortcut to bring the most recent window of that app?

Answer (score 1):

in macOS Monterey.  Holding down the **control key then clicking the window** can activate that window only.  Functionality Might be in early macOS also.

Answer (score 0):

you can press the **mission control** key (F3) and then select the window you need.